# fork() and shared variable

Tags: linux, fork

i have one problem:

```
int main(){
   int myVariable1 = 0;
   int myVariable2 = 0;
   pid_t t1 = fork();
   pid_t t2;
   if(t1 == 0){
       t2 = fork();
       if(t2 == 0) { myVariable1++; exit(1); }
       else if(t2 > 0) { myVariable2++; exit(1); }

       wait(0);
       wait(0);

      printf("myVariable1 = %d, myVariable2 =%d \n", myVariable1, myVariable2);

   }
```

and now input's:

```
myVariable1 = 0, myVariable2 = 0;
```

how can i get this values: 1 and 1? :>

Comment: by not exiting after you increment the variables? Right now you fork, do some addition, then quit. your wait/printf code is impossible to execute, UNLESS fork() fails for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Variables on different sides of a fork are *not* shared.

The fork duplicates the variables. When the child process exits, its version of the variables is lost.

Perhaps you would like to use `pthread_create()`? Then all variables are shared.

Comment: No, the fork is duplicating the entire address space (which contains variables, etc...)

Comment: I believe the proper response would be: "Yes, the fork is duplicating the entire address space".

Comment: I don't have now connect to linux-server, but I just stop read about this problem. I read few line about **volatile**. How are you think? It's good way to fight with problem? :-). My second idea, is that use wait(&status) and exit(status).

Comment: `volatile` tells the compiler not to make the assumption that a variable didn't change. Using `fork()` that won't make a difference, since it's not a shared variable. With threads you should indeed use that, and while you're at it, also use `sigatomic_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `clone(2)` with `CLONE_VM` in `flags` and a valid `child_stack` argument instead of using `fork(2)` so that the children share the same memory space as the parent.